# How do I apply the outputWithoutWhitespace() method? Java

Tags: java, whitespace

My current code is as follows, I need to print the user's input using the `outputWithoutWhitespace()` method but I am having a hard time understanding where to apply it/how to actually use it. I believe I should be using `\t`. How can I take away the whitespace when printing with the `outputWithoutWhitespace()` method?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextAnalyzer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = " ";
    int getNumOfCharacters = 0;
    int count = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter a sentence or phrase: ");
    userInput = scnr.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You entered: " + userInput);

    count = getNumOfCharacters(userInput);
    System.out.print("Number of characters: "+ count);
  }

  public static int getNumOfCharacters(String userInput) {
    int userCount = userInput.length();

    return userCount;
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `outputWithoutWhitespace()` and where is it declared/defined?

Comment: You will need to create the outputWithoutWhitespace() method and in the method use the String.replace() method such as: userInput.replace(" ", "");

Answer (score 0):

```
package whitesp;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextAnalyzer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = " ";
int getNumOfCharacters = 0;
int count = 0;

System.out.println("Enter a sentence or phrase: ");
  userInput = scnr.nextLine();
System.out.println("You entered: " + userInput);

count = getNumOfCharacters(userInput);
System.out.print("Number of characters: "+ count);
}

public static int getNumOfCharacters(String userInput) {
    String omitSpace=userInput.replace(" ","");

int userCount = omitSpace.length();


return userCount;
}

}
```